# React loading HOC: all the props provided in a list are set to optional and if any of them is undefined shows a spinner instead of the component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to make an HOC where I can provide an array of props and check whenever any of them is undefined: if so a Loading component with a spinner is shown instead of the wrapped component.

This was the easy part.

Since those props cannot be undefined (otherwise the spinner is shown) I want them to be optional props:

```
const MyComponentWithLoading = withLoading(MyComponent);

return (
  <MyComponentWithLoading
    loadingFields={['user']}
    user={user} // MyComponent requires "user" to not be undefined, but since it's in "loadingFields" it can actually be undefined
    device={device} // MyComponent requires "device" to not be undefined and it must be so because it's not in "loadingFields"
  />
);
```

I tried with the following code but it doesn't work. Any idea how to achieve this?

```
import React, {FC, ComponentType, PropsWithChildren} from 'react';
import Loading from '@components/Loading';

type WithLoadingProps<T> = {
  loadingFields?: Array<
    keyof Omit<PropsWithChildren<T & WithLoadingProps<T>>, 'loadingFields'>
  >;
};

const withLoading =
  <T,>(
    Component: ComponentType<T>,
  ): FC<
    Partial<Pick<T, keyof WithLoadingProps<T>['loadingFields']>> &
      Omit<T, keyof WithLoadingProps<T>['loadingFields']> &
      WithLoadingProps<T>
  > =>
  ({loadingFields: loadingData = [], ...otherProps}) => {
    const isLoading = (): boolean => {
      for (const key of loadingData) {
        if (otherProps[key] === undefined) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    };
    return isLoading() ? <Loading /> : <Component {...(otherProps as T)} />;
  };

export default withLoading;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the `loadingFields` property on the component is better placed as an argument to the higher-order function `withLoading`.

Let's start by defining some types:

```
type AllowUndefined<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] | undefined;
};

type SomeUndefined<T, A extends keyof T> = Omit<T, A> &
  AllowUndefined<Pick<T, A>>;
```

The `SomeUndefined` type allows us to make some fields in our type accept `undefined` as a value.

So, for type

```
type A = {
    a:number;
    b:string;
}
```

`type B = SomeUndefined<A, 'a'>` will yield a type

```
{
    a:number|undefined
    b:string
}
```

This will be useful later.

Now let's define `withLoading` with the additional parameter discussed above:

```
const withLoading = <T, A extends keyof T>(
  Component: ComponentType<T>,
  // readonly is important here so type-inference works correctly
  // require at least one value otherwise t-i breaks down
  loadingFields: readonly [A, ...A[]], 
): FC<SomeUndefined<T, A>> => (props) => {
  const isLoading: boolean = Object.entries(props).some(
    ([k, v]) => loadingFields.includes(k as A) && typeof v === "undefined",
  );
  return isLoading ? (
    <Loading />
  ) : (
    <Component {...(props as PropsWithChildren<T>)} />
  );
};
```

Now, say we have a simple component:

```
const Foo: FC<{ a: number; b: string }> = ({ a, b }) => (
  <div>
    {[...Array(a)].map((_, i) => (
      <div key={i}>{b}</div>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

We can wrap it and make some fields optional:

```
const LoadingFoo = withLoading(Foo, ["a"]);
```

meaning we can now use this new component:

```
<LoadingFoo a={undefined} b="hello" />
```

and we'll see a loading message,

otherwise:

```
<LoadingFoo a={10} b="hello" />
```

and we'll see a deployed component. Yay!

[CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-hill-c2o0r?file=/src/App.tsx)

### Edit

Alternatively, if you truly want the `loadingFields` prop on the "extended" component, you can:

```
function withLoadingOnComponent<T>(Component: ComponentType<T>) {
  return <A extends keyof T>({
    loadingFields,
    ...props
  }: PropsWithChildren<
    SomeUndefined<T, A> & { loadingFields: readonly [A, ...A[]] }
  >): JSX.Element => {
    const isLoading: boolean = Object.entries(props).some(
      ([k, v]) => loadingFields.includes(k as A) && typeof v === "undefined",
    );
    return isLoading ? <Loading /> : <Component {...(props as any)} />;
  };
}
```

then

```
const FWC = withLoadingOnComponent(Foo);
```

so you can:

```
<FWC loadingFields={["a"]} a={undefined} b={"hello"} />
```

I haven't figured out how to make it optional though.

Comment: I guess you're right and the more elegant (and simple) solution is to put the loading props in the HOC itself instead of the wrapped component props.

I tried to expand on your solution further but unfortunately I cannot figure out why I cannot convert otherProps to PropsWithChildren<T> whenever I destructure the props (without converting to unknown first): https://pastebin.com/eQR14bPe

Comment: Also for some reason it doesn't work if I omit the loadingFields and I add a default value equal to an empty array: all the props allow for undefined!

Comment: @darkbasic With no values in it, the type of the loadingFields array is inferred to be a union of all possible keys and things break down a bit. You can force the user to supply at least one value by specifying the type as `loadingFields: readonly [A, ...A[]]`

Comment: actually if the user provides an empty array it works quite well (none gets optional). The problem is if I make the field optional with a default value equal to an empty array: in such case all fields get optional. I don't know why and what's the difference. What I am trying to achieve is allowing loadingFields to be optional.