# Can't properly type the following HOC function accepting a custom property key

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I have an HOC function which takes a component and a property key, and returns the component with a value injected at the specified property key. This is my proof of concept:

```
import * as React from 'react'

type WrappedComponentProps<PropertyKey extends string> = {
  [k in PropertyKey]: boolean
}

type WithCustomPropertyProps<P, PropertyKey extends string> = Omit<P, PropertyKey> & P

const withCustomProperty = <
  PropertyKey extends string,
  P extends WrappedComponentProps<PropertyKey>,
  CurrWithCustomPropertyProps = WithCustomPropertyProps<P, PropertyKey>
>(propertyName: PropertyKey) => {
  return (WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P>): React.FC<CurrWithCustomPropertyProps> => {
    const WithMediaQuery: React.FC<CurrWithCustomPropertyProps> = (props: CurrWithCustomPropertyProps) => {
      return <WrappedComponent {...props} {...{ [propertyName]: true }} />
    }

    return WithMediaQuery
  }
}

type Props = {
  anotherProperty: string
} & WrappedComponentProps<'propertyKey'>

class Test extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return <div></div>
  }
}

const _test = withCustomProperty('propertyKey')(
  Test
)
```

But, as you can see in this [TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wQK81m), I get two errors:

```text
Type 'CurrWithCustomPropertyProps & { [x: string]: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & P & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Type 'CurrWithCustomPropertyProps & { [x: string]: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'P'.
    'P' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'CurrWithCustomPropertyProps & { [x: string]: boolean; }'.
```

```text
Argument of type 'typeof Test' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<WrappedComponentProps<"propertyKey">>'.
  Type 'typeof Test' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<WrappedComponentProps<"propertyKey">, any>'.
    Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
      Type 'WrappedComponentProps<"propertyKey">' is not assignable to type 'TestProps | Readonly<TestProps>'.
        Property 'anotherProperty' is missing in type 'WrappedComponentProps<"propertyKey">' but required in type 'Readonly<TestProps>'.
```

I admit I don't have any clues about what's happening here. The one above is one of the alternatives I tried, I tried several other ones, but couldn't get any improvement.

I guess I should link the component props of the component returned by the HOC function with the ones of the wrapped component, but I can't figure out how. Any ideas?

Comment: Too busy to answer, but I answered a similar question a few days ago that might inspire: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68511373

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is the following: you have one function with 3 type arguments. Type arguments are assigned actual types when you call the function. Let's look at the way you call it:

```
const _test = withCustomProperty('propertyKey')(Test)
```

Here you may think it's obvious that `PropertyKey` should be `"propertyKey"`, `P` should be `TestProps` and the third argument should be whatever it should, I'm out of cerebral powers to calculate what it is.

But let's rewrite it a bit

```
const hoc = withCustomProperty('propertyKey')
const _test = hoc(Test)
```

Now it's not so obvious, because these are basically 2 separate calls that have nothing to do with each other. You could as well do

```
const hoc = withCustomProperty('propertyKey')
const _test = hoc(Test)
const _test1 = hoc(SomeOtherComponentWithDifferentProps)
```

And it is still supposed to work. The problem is all 3 type arguments of `withCustomProperty` are decided on the first line and you cannot change them later. Even if you write `withCustomProperty(...)(Test)` in one line, they are still all decided during the first call and cannot be changed when you call it the second time with `Test` as argument. What types are assigned to them? Idk some junk, maybe `never` or something

So what you need to do is to decide only one type argument when you call `withCustomProperty` (that is, the `PropertyKey`) and the rest of them when you call whatever it returns with your `Test` component. So your `withCustomProperty` generic function should accept only 1 type argument that will be decided on its call and it should return another generic function that has the rest of the arguments to decide later. Here is what it looks like:

```
const withCustomProperty = <
  // Only one type argument here
  PropertyKey extends string
>(propertyName: PropertyKey) => {
  return <
    // We return a generic function and the rest of type arguments go here
    P extends WrappedComponentProps<PropertyKey>,
    CurrWithCustomPropertyProps = WithCustomPropertyProps<P, PropertyKey>
  >(WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P>): React.FC<CurrWithCustomPropertyProps> => {
    const WithMediaQuery: React.FC<CurrWithCustomPropertyProps> = (props: CurrWithCustomPropertyProps) => {
      return <WrappedComponent {...props} {...{ [propertyName]: true }} />
    }

    return WithMediaQuery
  }
}
```

This solves the error and that's pretty much it.

Also I'm not sure what is the purpose of this third argument, `CurrWithCustomPropertyProps`. Do you just use it as an alias for `WithCustomPropertyProps<P, PropertyKey>` so that you don't have to type it multiple times? If so, it's a very bad idea and will cause a lot of headache. Just define a type alias inside your function like this:

```
const withCustomProperty = <
  PropertyKey extends string
>(propertyName: PropertyKey) => {
  return <
    P extends WrappedComponentProps<PropertyKey>
  >(WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P>): React.FC<
    // You have to write the whole thing here, because type
    // aliases can only be declared in blocks
    WithCustomPropertyProps<P, PropertyKey>
  > => {
    // Define type alias here
    type RealProps = WithCustomPropertyProps<P, PropertyKey>

    const WithMediaQuery: React.FC<RealProps> = (props: RealProps) => {
      return <WrappedComponent {...props} {...{ [propertyName]: true }} />
    }

    return WithMediaQuery
  }
}
```

This gets rid of the second error. I didn't look into what exactly caused it, to be honest, if you actually need this third type argument, leave a comment and I'll try to update my answer to accomodate for it.

[Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=2&pln=9&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQLABQ9MAnmFnAOpTJisAmAwiUgA7LMJgAFYmFQAeKRFawmAaSxM4WAB4wxvdKhhRgwgOYA%20OAF44Ab3pw4AbQDWcE3AVLmapgF0ALjgAIwgIABscYXoAX3pGFjZ2YBgAC34AV0MSLyxlLzkJABpPaTyfdU0dPQMjEwtrOAB5EBT5EtzlX0sAMk94ulwIYUM4AHcU9KyYHLLlRtkHUsVy1UrtXWF9OENjM3pzAAowOeYAOWQQLCDOiqYASmtLezpHShgMqGE4RdfHTyqm22nG4fEE4GGYkk0kKpzWTHMSyOIJ4WAEQkh4iC2DwMAAdOCRFCACqJeTme7Yqj4gBi-FkyTSmWyIFuTAK7WW3nh5ksVmeS0czFYcEyUCgjKmLLZBUakuZM1ZcI5xS5q26A3%20cCGI3gkoAsmjgMgAIoZPJMKm4vF02RiiWTBWzFb5GF8uDHGFBe3y6bO7kFR78uyC-7vT7fBlcVHoiGicR2PFJk6KVAxRNJ2zOFPci5XQJwIzmuAxdMAekRf0ccQYVbg4a%20HEmht4xrNFqWNZrCRFxKwhllNhejmQwggaTybKCu3qsTgfRRYIx8ehqdkZBz6vUZEr9Fw4TQ6D7ow2NUw1IJy6hsmPq5kAr%20lC2eUOj2HYawH0bslbADdzLIZZ-pW1axAMOqjAA%20roow2BMTJ%20kqLrMIcG5wr4ZD3IcSy3vQ9z0EAA)